# Subalgebras of matrices property

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $g$ be a Lie subalgebra of $gl_n(\mathbb{C})$ which has the propety that if $a\in g$ then also $a^\dagger\in g$ (where $a^\dagger$ is conjugate transpose). I want to show that if $a$ is an ideal of $g$ then there is an ideal $b$ of $g$ with $g=a\oplus b$. I guess that given $a$ I should define $b=a^\dagger=\{x^\dagger \ | \ x\in a\}$. I can check that this is an ideal, but not that it has the above properties. Am I taking the wrong $b$?

Comment: Yes, you are ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: For examples, consider the situation in which g is one-dimensional, spanned by a symmetric matrix

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: so you are saying that the result is actually wrong? that's interesting. let me think about it

Comment: So i need to do some kind of case distinction?

Comment: I did not say that the result is wrong — it is true, in fact.What I am saying is that you are taking the wrong $b$, which was your question!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think $b$ can be taken to be the orthogonal complement with respect to the Frobenius inner product? Do you agree?

Comment: Well, does that work?